# WeakEventManager class not found

Tags: c#, .net

I'm attempting to inherit from the WeakEventManager class but the namespace can't be found in my project. I'm not sure what's going on as I have the using System.Windows; directive. I can load a project that uses this class successfully I just can't seem to implement it on my own. The project is .Net 4.5 and I'm unsure as to what's happening.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class lives in the `System.Windows` namespace, but is defined in the `WindowsBase` assembly. Make sure you have imported the `WindowsBase` assembly and added it as a reference to your project.

Comment: I've attempted this with no sucesss.

Comment: What I ended up doing was adding the .dll from the .Net 4.5 directory and that seems to have worked.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. Glad it worked. Are you using 4.5 for your entire project?

Comment: I've selected 4.5 on project creation. The odd thing was when I went to add my references what was listed was 4.0. I'm not sure what was going on. But I know it was 4.5 because you can't use System.Windows; by default on 4.0 projects. I think I may do a repair install of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer

1. open your project
2. right-click on References
3. click Add Reference
4. select .NET tab
5. select System.Windows
6. click OK

Comment: I did that initially and I still have the same results.

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer

1. open your project
2. right-click on References
3. click Add Reference
4. select .NET tab
5. select WindowsBase